# Combining duplicate rows in a 2dArray, while keeping the ones withought any duplicates

Tags: java, null, multidimensional-array

I have data in a 2d array, of `Object`s. I am looking for an algorithm which combines duplicate data, but my algorithm loses the ones which are duplicates. Also, it keeps all the rows on the top, so, my data is:

> ECE 201   Electrical and Computer Engineering I   2.6666666666666665
>
> BIO 101   Biology I   2.0
>
> CS 101    Computer Science I  3.5
>
> AE 101    Aerospace Engineering I 2.5
>
> BE 101    Biomedical Engineering I    2.0
>
> CS 101    Computer Science I  2.0
>
> CS 102    Computer Science II 3.0
>
> BE 100    Intro Biomedical Engineering    3.6
>
> ECE 200   Intro Electrical and Computer Engineering   3.5
>
> BIO 100   Intro Biology   2.2
>
> CS 101    Computer Science I  3.75
>
> AE 101    Aerospace Engineering I 1.6666666666666667
>
> BE 100    Intro Biomedical Engineering    1.2

but it is filled with `null`s. I use the following algorithm:

```
for (int i = 0; i< finalData.length; i++)
{
  if (finalData[i][1] != null)
  {
    String first = (String)finalData[i][1];
    for (int j = i; j< finalData.length; j++)
    {
      if (finalData[j][1]!= null)
      {
        String second = (String)finalData[j][1];
        if (first.equals(second))
        {
          double one = (double)finalData[i][6];
          double two = (double)finalData[i][6];
          finalData[i][7] = (one + two)/2;
          System.out.println("found!\t" + first + "\t" + second + "\t" +  finalData[i][7]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my data becomes:

> found!    ECE 201 ECE 201 2.6666666666666665
>
> found!    BIO 101 BIO 101 2.0
>
> found!    CS 101  CS 101  3.5
>
> found!    CS 101  CS 101  3.5
>
> found!    CS 101  CS 101  3.5
>
> found!    AE 101  AE 101  2.5
>
> found!    AE 101  AE 101  2.5
>
> found!    BE 101  BE 101  2.0
>
> found!    CS 101  CS 101  2.0
>
> found!    CS 101  CS 101  2.0
>
> found!    CS 102  CS 102  3.0
>
> found!    BE 100  BE 100  3.6
>
> found!    BE 100  BE 100  3.6
>
> found!    ECE 200 ECE 200 3.5
>
> found!    BIO 100 BIO 100 2.2
>
> found!    CS 101  CS 101  3.75
>
> found!    AE 101  AE 101  1.6666666666666667
>
> found!    BE 100  BE 100  1.2

//the found! is just for making sure that it was the right output.

How can I improve this algorithm to produce the desired result?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Can you please try to rephrase and explain what exactly are you after (and add a *simple* test case showing that is the input and what is the output you expect from the program to yield)

Comment: Instead of using `Object[][]`, can't you write a class and use `YourClass[]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing an algorithm, you can use a set or a hash table.

Sets are your better choice; they do not allow duplication.  You can read more about them here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Hash tables are a way to implement sets.  To use these, you would need to write a hashing function to turn your data into a hash key, then you would use that key to index into the table and store the unhashed value there.

Comment: I actually have no experience with hashing, so I can't use that method.

Comment: How about a set?  Sets are very easy, and I provided a link.  I think learning to use them will take less time than writing an algorithm or even trying to fix it.